# Calculate amount in SQL Server

Tags: stored-procedures, formula, computation

I have already created a SQL Server stored procedure to compute certain amount using the formula provided in my specs.

The formulas are:

```
ServiceFee = 25 / numberoftransaction 

WitholdingTaxOfServiceFee = (ServiceFee / 1.12) * 0.02
```

I'm having problem getting the correct result.

Ex.

```
numberoftransaction = 4

                    Service Fee    WithTaxOfServiceFee
Transaction1:           6.25              0.11
Transaction2:           6.25              0.11
Transaction3:           6.25              0.11
Transaction4:           6.25              0.11
```

Expected result if sum all the transaction should be 25 for service fee and 0.45 for `WithTaxOfServiceFee`. If I use Excel and apply the given formula the result is correct however in SQL Server it's not.

My question is, is there a better formula to get the correct result of 25 for Service fee and 0.45 for `WithTaxServiceFee`?

Comment: Well, ***show us*** the code! What is your T-SQL stored procedure? How should we be able to suggest anything if you're not showing us what you have????

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the precision, you use precision of 2 numbers after the decimal point.

Take a look at the difference between the following code

```
DECLARE @a1 Decimal (10,2) = 25.0/4
DECLARE @b1 Decimal (10,2) = (@a1 /1.12)*0.02

SELECT @a1, @b1
```

And this one:

```
DECLARE @a1 float = 25.0/4
DECLARE @b1 float = (@a1 /1.12)*0.02

SELECT @a1, @b1
```

Try changing the datatype of the variables to hold better accurate number, have a look at the possible datatypes under Exact Numerics section and Approximate Numerics sction:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx